# C# Addition on a double digit integer

Tags: c#

To be more specific, I would like to know how to make it so that i can accept a two digit input from a user and perform addition on the two digits.
Example:
userInput = 42;

4+2 = 6.
I could not find out the name of this action so i could not find such an answer on here.
I should add that i would rather avoid creating more integers

Comment: What have you tried? Have you taken each char of the string separately? and converted to an int? All the needed hints are here ;)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a method you can use. Just use a two character input `string` as a parameter. You'll either get an exception because the input `string` is invalid or the sum of both digits.

```
public int AddTwoDigitString(string input)
{
    if(input == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));

    if(input.Length != 2)
        throw new ArgumentException($"`{nameof(input)}` must be two characters long");

    int firstDigit, secondDigit;

    if(int.TryParse(input[0].ToString(), out firstDigit) == false)
        throw new ArgumentException("First character is not an integer.");

    if(int.TryParse(input[1].ToString(), out secondDigit) == false)
        throw new ArgumentException("Second character is not an integer.");

    return firstDigit + secondDigit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by yourself by calculating:

```
int b= Int32.Parse(userinput);
int a =b%10+b/10;
```

and than if b its 42, so a will be 2+4=6

if you don't know how many digits you have:

```
int b= Int32.Parse(userinput);
int a=0;
while(b!=0)
{
a+=(b%10);
b=b/10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, ill try converting it to an int and then doing what you said, but is there a way to do it for 3-5 digit number inputs?

Comment: yes, then you can do a while loop - I added it to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use `Aggregate` function from `System.Linq`  like this

```
return userInput.ToCharArray()
     .Aggregate(0, (result, character) => result += int.Parse(character.ToString()));
```

where the lamda expresion is the accumulator function that will be executed for each character in the input.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

int number;

```
{
Console.Write("Insert the number"); 
number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
Console.Write("Equals" + Addition(number).ToString());
Console.ReadKey();
}

// Operation that returns the addition of the digits of a number 

static int Addition(int number){
int acum = 0; 

while (num != 0){
var digit = number % 10;
acum += digit; 
number = number / 10; 
}

return acum;

        }
    }
}
```